# How to delete collection automatically in mongodb with pymongo ? (Django doesn't delete mongodb collection)

Tags: python, django, mongodb, nosql

I have Django app which creates collections in MongoDB automatically. But when I tried to integrate the delete functionality, collections that are created with delete functionality are not deleted. Collections that are automatically created are edited successfully. This method is called in another file, with all parameters.

An interesting thing to note is when I manually tried to delete via python shell it worked. I won't be deleting the collections which are not required anymore.

```
import pymongo
from .databaseconnection import retrndb #credentials from another file all admin rights are given

mydb = retrndb()
class Delete():
    def DeleteData(postid,name):
        PostID = postid
        tbl = name + 'Database'
        liketbl = PostID + 'Likes'
        likecol = mydb[liketbl]
        pcol = mydb[tbl]
        col = mydb['fpost']
        post = {"post_id":PostID}
        ppost = {"PostID":PostID}
        result1 = mydb.commentcol.drop() #this doesn't work
        result2 = mydb.likecol.drop() #this doesn't work
        print(result1,'\n',result2) #returns none for both
        try:
            col.delete_one(post) #this works
            pcol.delete_one(ppost) #this works
            return False
        except Exception as e:
            return e
```

Any solutions, I have been trying to solve this thing for a week.
Should I change the database engine as Django doesn't support NoSQL natively. Although I have written whole custom scripts that do CRUD using pymongo.